# Restart Windows' explorer.exe via QProcess

Tags: windows, qt, windows-explorer, qprocess

At first, the Windows `explorer.exe` was closed and the desktop screen went black. My program needs to start `explorer.exe`. This is I tried:

```
QProcess process;
process.execute("explorer.exe");
```

The problem is this only pops up a new explorer window instead of reactivating the desktop explorer (turn the black screen back to desktop). It should behave just like when you run `explorer.exe` after you kill it in `cmd` or `powershell`.

Comment: What windows version do you use? I've just checked your code on Windows 8.1 and it works as you expect.

Comment: Just tested it on 7 and it indeed just opened a new window without reactivating the desktop. Will try to fix that, it's really interesting.

Comment: My environment: Windows 10 64bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution found:

```
QProcess::startDetached("explorer.exe"); //Wrong
QProcess::execute("C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe"); //Wrong
QProcess::startDetached("C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe"); //Right
```

If anyone knows why `explorer.exe` behaviour like this, please share it.

Comment: Btw, you forgot double backslash `\\`

Comment: `execute` will start explorer and block your program until explorer finish working, and `startDetached` will start explorer on its own session and will not freeze your app. I actually was going to suggest you this, but on my win7 all these cases don't work.